# How do I make internal Markdown links generated by Nextjournal work with Jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have some markdown code which is rendered correctly on [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/app), but when I put it into my github pages website using Jekyll, my links (to external images, stored on the web) are not recognized. The markdown was auto-generated by [Nextjournal](https://nextjournal.com):

In the body of the markdown file, I have the following text:

```
![result][nextjournal#output#101f646d-64cd-43a3-bf98-9cbc58a5ea90#result]
```

At the end of the markdown file, the URL containing the image is actually specified:

```
[nextjournal#output#101f646d-64cd-43a3-bf98-9cbc58a5ea90#result]:
<https://nextjournal.com/data/QmVm2qrqEQxu171s5JKUdzpeqXZsKQaS9scnDtS9vUPyCX?content-type=image/svg%2Bxml&node-id=101f646d-64cd-43a3-bf98-9cbc58a5ea90&node-kind=output>
```

I realize that I can solve this problem by putting the full URL into the first link, but this will require a lot of manual editing. Is there a way to make such "internal" links work with Jekyll?

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#links), it looks like your code should work. What output are you getting? You'll probably need to run an instance of Jekyll on your computer to better troubleshoot.

Comment: See this test file on Github:
https://github.com/Emadmasroor/emadmasroor.github.io/blob/master/test.md

and the rendered web page:
https://emadmasroor.github.io/Test/

it seems that the Github navigation page renders it correctly, but the Jekyll engine (at least via Github pages) does not. I haven't yet tried a local instance of Jekyll on my computer, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line break in your reference.

What you have:

```
[nextjournal#output#101f646d-64cd-43a3-bf98-9cbc58a5ea90#result]:
<https://nextjournal.com/data/QmVm2qrqEQxu171s5JKUdzpeqXZsKQaS9scnDtS9vUPyCX?content-type=image/svg%2Bxml&node-id=101f646d-64cd-43a3-bf98-9cbc58a5ea90&node-kind=output>
```

What you should have:

```
[nextjournal#output#101f646d-64cd-43a3-bf98-9cbc58a5ea90#result]: <https://nextjournal.com/data/QmVm2qrqEQxu171s5JKUdzpeqXZsKQaS9scnDtS9vUPyCX?content-type=image/svg%2Bxml&node-id=101f646d-64cd-43a3-bf98-9cbc58a5ea90&node-kind=output>
```

Comment: Thanks! I followed your advice and also moved the part with `[nextjournal#output#101f646d-64cd-43a3-bf98-9cbc58a5ea90#result]: <https://nextjournal.com/data/QmVm2qrqEQxu171s5JKUdzpeqXZsKQaS9scnDtS9vUPyCX?content-type=image/svg%2Bxml&node-id=101f646d-64cd-43a3-bf98-9cbc58a5ea90&node-kind=output>` to the end of the file. It works now.